# Compilable/Executable Haskell Source Code Example

Tags: haskell, module, compilation, program-entry-point

I am learning Haskell as part of a Programming Languages course I am taking. I'm having quite a hard time understanding how to write entire Haskell programs. I understand basic syntax as used in GHCi, but my assignments require creating .hs files and compiling/executing them in Windows CMD, using commands:

```
ghc -o test test.hs
test.exe
```

If someone could explain how to write the following example then I think I will understand what I need in order to proceed.

```
module Main where
double :: Integer -> Integer
double x = x * 2

main :: IO ()
main = double 6
```

All I want to do here is to write a function that returns the double of an integer parameter, and have the main call that function with the parameter '6'. What should I be doing differently as far as separating the main module and function modules in the .hs file? Thanks for the help.

Comment: just change `double 6` into `print $ double 6` ... it will compile

Comment: to see why you should read a bit about `IO` (and the *feared* `IO` Monad)

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense because the main has to complete an I/O action, correct? What would it look like if I needed to do multiple tasks in the main?

Comment: it does not really have to do something but it needs to be of type `IO ()` (`main = return () ` would do nothing but still be ok) - if you want to do more than one thing you use `main = do \n firstThing \n secondThing \n ...` or use `sequence` (or `forM` or `mapM` or `>>=` or `>>`or ... the possibilities are really endless ;)) - but that should really be part of your course!

Comment: Thanks again. Yes it should certainly be a part of the course, unfortunately my professor is not great and has only taught us GHCi commands and not how to translate them into compilable source code. I appreciate the help, friend

Comment: you surely get to it - it's not unusual to postpone this stuff a bit till you are fit to handle the monad stuff

Comment: @possum_pendulum also, add an optimization flag like `-O` or `-O2` when compiling.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that when GHC is compiling your code it expects `main` to have a type suitable for the entry point to your program. It needs to have the type of "code which does input-output" because otherwise a Haskell program doesn't actually do anything observable!

That is, it expects to find `main :: IO X` for some `X`. It's considered good practice to have `main :: IO ()` which signifies that `main` is some program which does input-output and finally produces `()`, a trivial result.

Currently you have `main :: Integer`, a type error. Fixing this demands you decide what you want your program to do when run, a good default is printing something. We can use the function `print :: Show a => a -> IO ()` which will convert the supplied value to a string using `show` and print it to standard out. So we can write

```
 main :: IO ()
 main = print (double 6)
```

And everything will work just like you're at the REPL.

In general, read more about `IO` in [Real World Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/io.html). It's perfectly possible to use it without understanding monads or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

"my assignments require..." then ask your instructor. Check first whether she already gave you the answer (in the problem statement, or in class).